# Environment Variables not being saved in Max OS Sierra

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I have recently upgraded my OS to Max OS Sierra and I am trying to save one specific path in the environment variable(PATH variable).
I opened Terminal and executed below steps:

1. echo $PATH

   > /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
2. export PATH=~/Desktop/:$PATH
3. echo $PATH

   > /Users/pratik/Desktop/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr
   >   /local/bin

I have closed the Terminal and opened new Terminal and executed below command:

1. echo $PATH

   > /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

So the path which I have added previously is not getting saved.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

The `~/.bash_profile` is executed each time you open a terminal session(Terminal application) automatically.

So you need to set(export) your environment variables in `~/.bash_profile`

1. First, check if `.bash_profile` exists in logged in user home(`/Users/username`) directory.
2. If not exists then you can create `~/.bash_profile`. The easiest way to create it by the touch utility:  `touch .bash_profile'`. You can edit it using any text editor.
3. Now edit the .bash_profile : `vi ~/.bash_profile`
4. Add `export PATH=/Users/username/Desktop:$PATH` and save
5. Close the existing Terminal and open a new one.
6. Type `echo $PATH` and view the output. Newly added path(`/Users/username/Desktop`) must be stored in the PATH variable.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you export an environment variable, that applies only to the current session. If you want to permanently add something to your `PATH`, you should do it in your `.profile` script, which should go in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS Monterey - Version 12.4, neither ~/.bash_profile nor .profile is working. Creating .zprofile worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

## First Install "adb" as command

1- print

```
echo $path
```

2- open editor

```
vim /etc/paths
```

3- to make “insert” mode
Click on “I”

4- copy/past the environment variable example:

```
/Users/abdallahandroid/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
/Users/abdallahandroid/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
/Users/abdallahandroid/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
```

5- Press ""Esc"" then write + write colon”:” it will navigate to last line of editor

6- write “wq” + click enter

7- close terminal and open again, test print

```
echo $path
```

## Case when save print error "E212" see

[bug: vim when save print "/etc/paths" E212:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75660907/bug-vim-when-save-print-etc-paths-e212/75660914#75660914)