# bug: vim when save print "/etc/paths" E212:

Tags: vim

after open "vim" editor by termnial try to save the path enviroment
when write ":qw" it's print error:

vim when save print "/etc/paths" E212

Answer (score 1):

Your system comes with a number of executables by default, placed in a number of standard directories.

When a program is executed in a shell, say `$ vim`, the shell tries to find a `vim` executable in those directories and then tries to execute the first one it found, if any.

Those standard directories, listed in `/etc/paths`, are all owned by `root` because allowing any less privileged process to remove or add or change anything there could have very bad consequences.

`/etc/paths` is also owned by `root` because messing with that file could also have very bad consequences, from making default programs inaccessible to overriding them with malevolent ones.

It is thus not a good idea *at all* to change the file's permissions.

If you really want to, say, add a directory to that file, then the only appropriate method is to do it "as `root`", with `$ man sudo` (recommended reading):

```
$ sudo -e /etc/paths
```

Answer (score -2):

### error

```
 "/etc/paths" E212: Can't open file for writing Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

### problem:

Not have permission to edit

### termninal write:

```
sudo chmod  -R 777 /etc/paths
```

### On Mac Edit File Permission

1- Search for file by finder >> go >> type “/etc/paths/“

2- Then right click on file >> file info >> permission >> click icon add (+)

3- select your account and give access read and write

Comment: No, that is not a proper solution at all.

Comment: It's working very good with me

Comment: Cutting off your legs also works "very good" if you want to lose some weight.